# Using regex to reject a format string containing unrecognised parameters

Tags: python, regex

I have a situation where the user can enter a format string and I want to perform a validation check which rejects format strings containing invalid parameters.

For example, say the only valid parameters are {one}, {two}, and {three}, the following should be invalid because it contains {four}, which is not recognised.

```
This is {one} an {four} example.
```

I've spent ages trying to come up with a regex that will do the job, but have had no luck.

My best attempt is

```
def is_valid(template):
    return re.search(r'\{(?!one|two|three).*\}', template) is None
```

But this matches `{onee}` and `{twoawoinfwnfaf}`.

Comment: Maybe just [`\{(?:one|two|three)}`](https://regex101.com/r/sN6qM7/1) is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `}` to your lookahead assertion:

```
def is_valid(template):
    return re.search(r'\{(?!(?:one|two|three)\}).*\}', template) is None
```

Comment: Thanks. Or even more simply r'\{(?!(?:one|two|three)\})'

Answer (score 2):

How about an [`EAFP` approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). Try formatting the string and handle the `KeyError`:

```
f = "This is {one} an {four} example."

try:
    s = f.format(one="one", two="two", three="three")
    print("Valid format string")
except KeyError:
    print("Invalid format string")
```